# JPQL query to return a custom DTO, coming from a parent entity and it's nested/child entity, WITH NULLABLE NESTED ENTITY

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm currently struglling with a JPQL custom query supposed to be simple, at least at first glance.

Stack: Java 11, spring-boot 2.4.5, spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.4.8, hibernate-core 5.4.16, Postgre database.

***CASE***

**I just need my JPQL query to retrieve 3 fields, coming from a parent entity and it's child/nested entity (mapped as a one to one unidirectional relationship), in a custom DTO, instead of an entity from the domain.**

*The domain is like this:*

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Item")
public class ItemEntity {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  private String field1;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "nestedEntity_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private NestedEntity nestedEntity;
  //...
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Nested")
public class NestedEntity {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  private String field1;

  @NotNull
  private String field2;
  //...
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyDTO {
  @NotNull
  private String myField;

  private String concatedNestedFields;

  private String otherNestedField;
  //...
}
```

I thought it was easy, and did something like this:

```sql
@Query("SELECT new my.package.MyDto(itemEntity.field1, CONCAT(itemEntity.nestedEntity.field1, ' ', itemEntity.nestedEntity.field2), itemEntity.nestedEntity.field3) FROM ItemEntity itemEntity WHERE itemEntity.country = :country")
MyDTO findByCountry(@Param("country") CountryEnum country);
```

***PARTICULARITY***

I don't know if it is relevant or not, but the nested entity fields are `@NotNull` annotated.

***PROBLEM***

The problem occurs when the nestedEntity is null: the query return nothing, despite the 'parent' ItemEntity exists.
If the nestedEntity is not null, the query works.

***WHAT I TRIED***

**I tried to use the COALESCE() function**, which returns the first non null value from the parameters we give, on every nestedEntity field, as following:

```sql
@Query("SELECT new my.package.MyDto(itemEntity.field1, COALESCE(CONCAT(itemEntity.nestedEntity.field1, ' ', itemEntity.nestedEntity.field2),'-'), COALESCE(itemEntity.nestedEntity.field3), '-') FROM ItemEntity itemEntity WHERE itemEntity.country = :country")
MyDTO findByCountry(@Param("country") CountryEnum country);
```

**But it doesn't work either.**

---

*UPDATE*
I just tried something to eliminate some root causes.
If I run a JPA Named query provided by spring-data / JPA and returning the entity instead of my custom DTO, it works, even with a nested entity null. It does retrieve the entity with it's nested null entity.
The query is like:

```java
ItemEntity findItemEntityByCountry(@Param("country") CountryEnum country);
```

I'm not sure what to conclude about that, but it may help those who understand JPA better than me (and that's a lot of people... XD).

I didn't find any online resources for that case and I'm a bit lost.

**I would be very grateful if you guys could help me with this little surprisingly tricky query!**

Thanks a lot for your time guys! Hope this can help others too :)

Comment: Your problem is that the `.` i.e. navigation operator has inner join semantics according to the JPA specification, so if the association is null, the whole row is filtered out due to that. To resolve that, you have to left join the association and use the alias of the join instead of the full path when passing to the constructor expression.

Answer (score 1):

try the following left join

```
@Query("SELECT new my.package.MyDto(itemEntity.field1,
                        CONCAT(nestedEntity.field1, ' ', nestedEntity.field2),
                        nestedEntity.field3)
        FROM ItemEntity itemEntity left join itemEntity.nestedEntity as nestedEntity
        WHERE itemEntity.country = :country")
MyDTO findByCountry(@Param("country") CountryEnum country);
```

otherwise don't use concat and simply pass nestedEntity.field2 and do the concatenation java side

Comment: Thank for the answer but unfortunately, this isn't working for me. I still have an empty return, with or without using the CONCAT function...